# HP-UX swinstall error "INDEX file on the source did not exist or could not be read." with a hand-crafted depot

Tags: hp-ux, swinstall

I want to create a simple(?) software distribuition(package/SD-UX) containing a simple hello world shell script **without** using any tools provided by hpux for CI/CD reasons.

I have handcrafted [this layout](https://github.com/amreo/helloworld-hpux) copying from the latest cURL depot, chmodded to root:sys, and archived with `tar -C helloworld-hpux -czvf helloworld-7.6.6.depot.tar.gz .` but when I'm swinstalling it, I get a I/O error.

swagentd log:

```
       * Registered RPC protocol "ncacn_ip_tcp" with endpoint "2121".
       * Registered RPC protocol "ncadg_ip_udp" with endpoint "2121".
       * Checking job queue at 1 minute intervals.
       * Started install agent on "/" for root@sovmh123.siteox.com,
         pid=25798, 09/26/19 04:48:54 CDT
       * Started source agent on "/tmp/helloworld-7.6.6.depot.gz" for
         root@sovmh123.siteox.com, pid=25799, 09/26/19 04:48:55 CDT
ERROR:   The INDEX file on the source did not exist or could not be
         read.
ERROR:   The target "/tmp/helloworld-7.6.6.depot.gz" could not be
         opened. pid=25799 09/26/19 04:48:55 CDT
       * Agent pid=25799 completed.  09/26/19 04:48:55 CDT
       * Agent pid=25798 completed.  09/26/19 04:48:55 CDT
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `swinstall` has been enhanced in the last 5 or so years, I don't think it can read a gzipped `.depot.gz`. You must `gunzip` it to provide a plain `.depot`.

As far as I know, the INDEX file is a serialization of a set of hierarchical structures: you should check the `swpackage(4)` man page and compare the structure of the INDEX file to the structure of the described Package Specification File (PSF). The INDEX file has some more elements, but the overall structure should be similar.

Looks like the `helloworld-hpux/catalog/INDEX` is missing a `product` line. In other words:

```
...
media 
sequence_number 1
tag helloworld
data_model_revision 2.40
instance_id 1
control_directory helloworld
revision 7.66.0
title "helloworld"
...
```

should probably be:

```
...
media 
sequence_number 1
product
tag helloworld
data_model_revision 2.40
instance_id 1
control_directory helloworld
revision 7.66.0
title "helloworld"
...
```

`media` does not exist in the PSF syntax, but it probably identifies various tapes/CDs/other media containing various parts of the software distribution, if there is more than one, so it is probably a subcontainer in the INDEX syntax that contains any number of `product` sub-subcontainers.

Even in the PSF, there must be at least one `product` container, and `tag`, `control_directory`, `revision` and `title` are all applicable to `product` in PSF syntax. `data_model_revision` and `instance_id` are not directly documented in the PSF, but they are mentioned on the `swpackage(4)` man page in `product` or `bundle`-level contexts. Later, you have a `subproduct`, which must be a subcontainer of `product`.